# Swift upload image using REST API

Tags: php, ios, swift, laravel

I try to upload a UIImage to a webserver using a REST API, I got an 500 error. Is there something wrong with the swift code or the php code? I can't find any error's on the webserver.

```
func UploadRequest(image: UIImage)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://server-to-upload-file.com")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        //define the multipart request type

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if (image == nil)
        {
            return
        }

        let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)


        if(image_data == nil)
        {
            return
        }


        let body = NSMutableData()

        let fname = "test.png"
        let mimetype = "image/png"

        //define the data post parameter

        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(image_data!)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



        request.httpBody = body as Data



        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print(dataString)

        }

        task.resume()


    }


    func generateBoundaryString() -> String
    {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }
```

Comment: 500 errors are generally specifically server errors, so something is happening there. An error is occurring in your backend so a good place to start is finding out what that error is and working backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 is a server error. Basically any exception in server code produce this code.
I'm trying to say that your server code can be right and is crashing because of wrong data being sent from iOS device OR you are sending data in right format but your server is not receiving it properly.

You should read error log of your server to find out more.